# Can I build action bar in fragment?

Tags: android, build, android-actionbar, fragment

I have application where I build action bar in activity class. Can I build it in fragment ? Here is my code for action bar in activity.

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

    public static Context appContext; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    //ActionBar
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);




    View view = LayoutInflater.from(actionBar.getThemedContext()).inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    actionBar.setCustomView(view);
```

How can I build it in fragment ? Is it possible ? Something like this ?

```
public class VideoFragment extends Fragment{
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
       actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
       actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
       actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
       actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
       actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);


       View view = LayoutInflater.from(actionBar.getThemedContext()).inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);
       ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
       actionBar.setCustomView(view);


      return inflater.inflate(
      R.layout.mein_fragment, container, false);


}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `ActionBar` in your `Fragments` like this:

```
getActivity().getActionBar()
```

So yeah, you can do this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
```